# LuaInterface - RegisterFunction Object Reference

Tags: c#, exception, luainterface

I'm trying to integrate LuaInterface into C# and I am getting an `System.NullReferenceException` when I am trying to bind an C# function to Lua. The code I am trying to compile and run is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using LuaInterface;

namespace Hobot
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program program = new Program();
            Lua lua = new Lua();
            lua.RegisterFunction("puts", null, typeof(Program).GetMethod("Test"));
            lua.DoFile("test.lua");
        }

        private void Test(String text)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(text);
        }
    }
}
```

And when I run this code I get an `System.NullReferenceException` with `Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` saying it broke down on the `RegisterFunction` method.

Answer (score 3):

You have *null* in the target parameter of the RegisterFunction.

Try this:

```
lua.RegisterFunction("puts", this, typeof(Program).GetMethod("Test"));
```

Comment: Did not work, tried both running `lua.RegisterFunction("puts", Program, typeof(Program).GetMethod("Test"));` and using the one you said inside an member function of `Program`. Got the same error as before.

Comment: I do it like this: `lua.RegisterFunction("puts", this, this.GetType().GetMethod("Test"));`

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is old, but seeing as there's no answer here I hope this is ok:

It's failing because "Test" is private. Change it to

```
public void Test(String text)
{
    Console.WriteLine(text);
}
```

And use

```
lua.RegisterFunction("puts", this, GetType().GetMethod("Test"));
```

That should fix it (:

Comment: It's perfectly ok and it's a nice way to gain knowledge and reputation ;) Cannot upvote because it's not my field...